# Summernote set empty in my bean property

Tags: jquery, jsf, summernote

I'm trying to use Summernote with JSF but i have the following problem: When i send the request (from ajax) my bean property is empty (not null).

See my summernote code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Texto</label>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{cursoMB.questao.questao.texto}"
                    disabled="#{cursoMB.questao == null}"
                    styleClass="summernote form-control" />
            </div>
```

And my jQuery to use summerNote:

```
jQuery('.summernote').summernote({
     height: 300,                 // set editor height

      minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
      maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor

      focus: false                 // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote      
   });
```

See my button that should send the property values:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{cursoMB.salvarQuestao()}"
                styleClass="btn btn-default" title="clique para salvar a questão">
                <f:ajax execute="divQuestao" render="divTeste divQuestao" 
                onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'success') initSummerNote();  }" />
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i>
            </h:commandLink>
```

In my ManagedBean the value "texto" is empty. If i disable summernote everything works fine. 
In browser console don't have any error.

Comment: That can happen if it's disabled. Can you guarantee that `#{cursoMB.questao}` is never null, also not when the form is being submitted?

Comment: My inputTextArea is disabled in default because "questao" is null until user click in "insert button" and "questao" object is created.

Comment: @BalusC, some suggestion ?